# Bluetooth SDP Failed in some devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to work with a Bluetooth example, which should connects an Android client application to a Bluetooth server application running in PC (Java app, uses Bluecove library) using 'rtspp' protocol.

As a first phase of development I implemented a running model and that sample app smoothly runs in all tested Samsung devices, but not with HTC devices.

While trying with HTC devices, it showing a SDP failed IO Exception on connect.

Here is my code for server app, which run as java desktop application;

```
String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=MyAppSDPName";
StreamConnectionNotifier notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);
StreamConnection connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
...
```

This server application is running successfully and waiting for incoming connections...

This is my client side code which is run as Android application;

```
BluetoothDevice mmDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
BluetoothSocket mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
mmSocket.connect();
```

While running this application in Samsung devices there is no issues..
But when it is from hts devices, it is throwing `IOException`which states that `SDP failed`

Can anyone please show some light on this issue with HTC devices?
Tested with HTC Devices with Android 2.2 and 4.0 OS

Answer (score 0):

As happens with some manufacturers, HTC has a slightly different bluetooth stack implementation, so that could be the reason why SDP doesn't work properly.

Comment: then, how can I achieve a good solution, could you please suggest me any?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I'm facing a similar problem now, working with HID and SDP, because of the android bluetooth stack (BlueZ). I don't know why, but it doesn't provide the full behaviour it would have in a regular linux. For instance, it is not possible to have L2CAP server sockets listening to incomming connection.

If the problem is only with HTC, then it's because their stack doesn't support this feature, and I don't know if it is possible to change it, though I highly doubt it.